# Can you loop a do try catch block in Swift?

Tags: swift, error-handling, try-catch

My question is on the best practice around looping a do, try, catch block.

I have a login button that performs form validation using a do, try, catch block to catch invalid emails etc. It then performs a networking function.

Upon catching an error I display a UIAlertController.

If a user enters something into the form that throws an error and then corrects themselves the networking request never triggers because the error has been thrown.

**Simple Example Code:**

```
func loginButtonPressed {
    do {
        try someFormValidation()
    } catch {
        LoginError.invalidEmail
    }
    someNetworkingFunction()
}
```

My question is what is the best way/best practice to have a user loop back and trigger the do, try, catch block from the beginning so that when they get it right the networking request will trigger?

Maybe I trigger some code when they accept and dismiss the Alert? Open to hear peoples thoughts.

Comment: Your code is wrong. You will go on to the networking function even if there is an error.

Comment: Do you suggest placing it in the Do block? - Even if you do this the problem still remains.